# jQuery Isotope / Masonry - on reLayout the arrangement gets a bit messed up?

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

Ok, I can't figure out why this is happening... when the page is initially loaded:

http://tinyurl.com/af86wv5

clicking on an item and Galleria kicking in, opening up the maximized gallery of images, and all the other thumbnail items being rearranged perfectly around the maximized galleria div works just fine.

but if I click on one of the items in the nav menu (up top) to reLayout and filter the thumbs, and then click on any of them to open up a maximized Galleria gallery of images, the thumbnail items are not being arranged around the maximized image properly anymore - there are gaps, blank areas, inconsistencies... why?

I can't figure it out. What am I doing wrong/missing?

Also, how do I scroll the page to the next maximized gallery div/image? If a user clicks on a thumbnail on the bottom of the page, the maximized image will open up below the bottom of the browser - how can I animate scroll down to that specific image so it shows up on top of the user's browser instead, in clear focus?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see from your JS that `$container.isotope({layoutMode:'fitRows'})` is being set when a nav item is clicked on. Being as the issue only starts once a filtering option is chosen this may be affecting the grid layout. Does it help solve the issue if this...

```
$container.isotope({
    filter: selector,
    layoutMode : 'fitRows',
    animationOptions: {
        duration: 750,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false,
    },
});
```

is just replaced by this? (or possibly use the 'masonry' layoutMode instead)...

```
$container.isotope({
    filter: selector
});
```

On your second point (scrolling to an open item) in the past I have just used `scrollTo()` within a `setTimeout()` function when the item is opened. It is crude but enables the browser to find the correct element position after Isotope has re-arranged itself, any 'opening' or 'closing' logic can go in there as well to do the different bits when required.

If you need something a bit more logical to follow in the code then you could also try binding `scrollTo()` to the "transitionend" events to make sure Isotope is finished before animating the scroll.

Comment: I dunno why and how, but that $container suggestion worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I feel strange that you use `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;` and then use `translate3d`. Maybe you should try with `display: inline-block` without setting `position`.

Comment: I've tried using inline-block on gallery-stage, not much difference. And where do you notice translate3d used?

Comment: <div class="item web isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">

Comment: that's added dynamically by the Isotope/Masonry JS... not much I can do about that, as it's added on load. what would removing that do anyway?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't use Isotope/Masonry so I don't know how to remove. Another guess is to save the html before and after you click on nav. Then diff the htmls to see what's changed.

Comment: umm, yeah, I don't think that will work... especially with things dynamically changing on the site.